# Creating multiple columns from a single column by different delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column within an SQL table. The column is "Dam"

```
SELECT Dam
FROM [dbo].[names]
```

For most of the data within the column it comes in the following format

Marathon Nella (Jpn)1942

I would like to UPDATE the database to split the column into three with

```
Dam_Name = Marathon Nella
Dam_Country = Jpn
Dam_YOB = 1942
```

Occasionally/Rarely I have only the Dam_Name value in the field and there is no ( to act as a delimiter. In that case I would like to have the Dam_Name stay as is, and the Dam_Country and Dam_YOB to be NULL

I had looked at PARSENAME but I wasnt sure how to structure that of if there was a more efficient way to update the database.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, string extraction is not so easy in SQL Server.  Assuming the country is three characters:

```
select left(dam, charindex('(', dam + ' (') - 2) as name,
       nullif(left(stuff(dam, 1, charindex('(', dam + '('), ''), 3), '') as country,
       nullif(stuff(dam, 1, charindex(')', dam + ')'), ''), '') as dob
from (values ('Marathon Nella (Jpn)1942'), ('testing a')) v(dam)
```

This can be adjusted if these conditions are not true, but this gives an idea on what to do.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=279218a064cfc50d791aea441481c743) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! I'd like to update the DB rather than just select it so is it just replacing select with UPDATE dbo.names and then SET or do I have to create the columns first?

Comment: @ByronRogers . . . You should be able to use these expressions in an `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with XML tricks:

```
;WITH splitValues AS
(
SELECT id,
           LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)'))) AS splitValue, 
           CASE ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) WHEN 1 THEN 'Name' WHEN 2 THEN 'Country' ELSE 'YOB' end AS columnHeader
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id,
               CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData><ColumnData>'
                    + REPLACE(REPLACE(string, '(', '</ColumnData><ColumnData>'), ')', '</ColumnData><ColumnData>')
                    + '</ColumnData></RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS xmlString
        FROM #x
    ) xmlTable
        CROSS APPLY xmlString.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData/ColumnData') m(n))

This gives you results like:
========================
id    splitValue       columnHeader
1     Marathon Nella   Name
1     Jpn              Country
1     1942             Year
```

Next Update your table:

```
   UPDATE table
   SET Name = splitValue
   From table INNER JOIN
        splitValues ON table.Id = splitValues.Id AND columnHeader = 'Name'
```

etc